# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'fancybox' in Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox, nomethoderror

I have the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'fancybox'

in my JS console on this website http://www.e-fashion-awards.com/

As you can see, I include jquery.fancybox.js after jquery.min.js and I include jquery only once (saw in other topics).

Here is the piece of buggy code including the js files includes and the fancybox call :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fancybox-css'  href='http://www.e-fashion-awards.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/fancybox/fancybox.css?ver=3.1.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.e-fashion-awards.com/wordpress/wp-includes/js/l10n.js?ver=20101110'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.1.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.e-fashion-awards.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?ver=1.3.4'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.e-fashion-awards.com/wordpress/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.e-fashion-awards.com/wordpress/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<link rel='index' title='E-Fashion Awards &#8211; Concours Jeunes Créateurs' href='http://www.e-fashion-awards.com/' />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.1.2" />

<!-- Start Of Script Generated By cforms v11.7.3 [Oliver Seidel | www.deliciousdays.com] -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.e-fashion-awards.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/cforms/styling/cforms.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.e-fashion-awards.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/cforms/js/cforms.js"></script>
<!-- End Of Script Generated By cforms -->


<!-- Fancybox for WordPress v3.0.1 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){

jQuery.fn.getTitle = function() { // Copy the title of every IMG tag and add it to its parent A so that fancybox can show titles
    var arr = jQuery("a.fancybox");
    jQuery.each(arr, function() {
        var title = jQuery(this).children("img").attr("title");
        jQuery(this).attr('title',title);
    })
}

// Supported file extensions
var thumbnails = jQuery("a:has(img)").filter( function() { return /(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$/i.test(jQuery(this).attr('href')) });

thumbnails.addClass("fancybox").attr("rel","fancybox").getTitle();

jQuery("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'cyclic': false,
    'autoScale': true,
    'padding': 1,
    'opacity': true,
    'speedIn': 500,
    'speedOut': 500,
    'changeSpeed': 300,
    'overlayShow': true,
    'overlayOpacity': "0.8",
    'overlayColor': "#000000",
    'titleShow': true,
    'titlePosition': 'inside',
    'enableEscapeButton': true,
    'showCloseButton': false,
    'showNavArrows': true,
    'hideOnOverlayClick': true,
    'hideOnContentClick': true,
    'width': 560,
    'height': 340,
    'transitionIn': "fade",
    'transitionOut': "fade",
    'centerOnScroll': true
});
```

So I really don't know where my error come from...

Any idea ?

Comment: Once the link is gone this question will be of no use to future users.

Comment: Ok I will detail my question a little more here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if (thumbnails.length>0) thumbnails.fancybox(//...
```

or `$(".fancybox")` if thumbnails is not good enough for fancybox

since in fact i don't see any links to any image on homepage, it could be the reason

Comment: Thank you but what do you mean by plugin instantiation ?

Comment: And I know this file is a real mess but I didn't do that I just have to make it a little less buggy...

Comment: it is when you call a plugin, you create an instance of that plugin

Comment: @cocoggu you didn't fix that bit `<script type="text/javascript">
var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({ ` what is this fadeSlideShow ? load the js before or remove that script

Comment: Yes I understand but I mean which plugin ? I change this : jQuery(function(){}); with jQuery(function($,undefined) {}); but it didn't change anything. I will try to wrap the fadeSlideShow new instance.

Comment: Ok I wrapped this bit script but I still have my main error. I guess this script is to init the slideshow on the index page.

Comment: I can also say that this fancybox error happen only on the index page, the other pages have the same script in the header and it works great

Comment: Ok this condition work great : "if (thumbnails.length>0) thumbnails.fancybox(" !!! But a lot of other pages didn't have thumbnails and the script works well, so I don't think that the error occurs because there no thumbnails on the page... But at least it bypass it ! Thank you a lot mikakun !

Answer (score 0):

I could't see your js, but this error look like you are calling the `fancybox` this way:

```
object.fancybox()
```

and the correct way is:

```
$(object).fancybox()
```

Comment: Thank you, however my call looks like this : jQuery("a.fancybox").fancybox({ ... });